# Submitting a BIO from a work queue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I'm using 2.6.39.1 version of the Linux kernel. In my block device driver, I'm queuing a `struct work_struct` from the bottom half of the interrupt handler, i.e., in the `->bi_end_io` function of a previously submitted BIO. The work queue handler function then submits the next BIO to be processed. The system becomes unresponsive when we do this. We believe that calling `submit_bio()` from our work queue handler function in this setup is causing the problem. Can someone explain what the problem is in this scenario?